# Google Sign-In Prompt on Android Accessibility

Tags: android, google-play, google-signin

The Google Sign-in experience on Android is broken on smaller screens (Samsung S9 pictured), and system font scaling nearing 2.0f. As a developer, **are there any configuration options available to make this screen more accessible**? Our implementation is basically derived from [the official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin#kotlin+ktx_2).

The middle part of the screen should display account information, but gets truncated by the header and the footer. The account picker itself is scrollable, so if at least a small portion of it is showing, the user can technically use it. If, however, it gets clipped completely like in my example, you can't access the relevant account picker part even with TalkBack.

[image: Samsung S9 Demonstrating the issue]

*The image is edited to remove the app name and logo.*

Comment: This is reported issue in bug tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172544276 :( Nov 2020...

Comment: @Sigute I have no idea how you find anything in there. But since it’s almost a year old, and we still have zero comments on that from Google, the question on workaround still stands.